# Is there a website that shows historic price data?

Tags: mtgox, exchange-rate

I need to find what the Bitcoin-Mt. Gox USD price was at certain historic dates and times (exact timestamp).

Is there a website where I can input a specific historic date+time, and get the rate for that time?

I believe that [Bitcoin Chart's API](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/) might do the trick ... but I'm asking about a website with a UX, not an API.

Comment: Do you need granularity finer than once a day?

The daily data is available here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmcTCtjBoRWUdHJuUE1mUkFxa3A0eHBDQkxZLVVFZmc

Because Google docs spreadsheet data can be queried as an API, a javascript front end that queries a specific day could be easily created.

Comment: @StephenGornick - I do. I need a specific timestamp in a specific day (GMT).

Comment: @StephenGornick Why is that spreadsheet discontinued?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should help:
http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/

Here you can view all the historical data:
http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#tgSzm1g10zm2g25zv

And if you need any specific date you can hit "Custom time". :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The daily candles are visualized nicely here: https://satoshi.camp/stats/mtgoxhistory/usd